# Does Bash execute commands sequentially or in parallel when operators(and, or) exist?

Tags: bash, pipe, operator-keyword

I understand when commands with pipes, they are executed in parallel by bash.
( `cat sth | grep ho | cat` )

But when the commands with '&&' or '||' operators, I thought the commands are executed sequentially. But in these cases below, bash execute the second command and the second command wait for user to input something.
`(ls || wc) | pwd` or `(ls || cat) | pwd`

but in these cases below, it sometimes wait for input, sometimes doesn't wait for input...
`(ls || wc) | ls` or `(ls || cat) | ls`

when I check the process at first case, 'wc' or 'cat' process is alive and check the `lsof -p (process id)`, 'wc' or 'cat' command's fd '1' TYPE is PIPE and connect to somewhere, and fd '0' (stdin) wait for user to input something.

So in conclusion, I don't know why the second command is executed even though they are behind the '||' operator so they don't need to be executed because the first command is exit with 0.

Comment: It's called a *race condition*; if the lefthand side of the pipe attempts to write to standard output after the righthand side terminated, the command that did the attempt receives a SIGPIPE and returns non-zero (that's why `wc` or `cat` is run). `pwd` is more likely to cause this because it's a shell builtin and thus quicker to return than external utilites.